# CSS: why do the heights of div blocks change with content?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS & Html. I've created a page with two div blocks: header block (above) and a main content block (below). Nested in the content block are three further div blocks that I would like inline with each other. When the nested blocks only have simple text the layout is perfect. When content is added eg header text or Django content the vertical position of the nested blocks change in relation to each other. Why is this? Here's the basic code I'm using

```
<div id="contentBlock">
            <div id = "leftBlock">
                leftBlock
            </div>
            <div id = "centreBlock" >
                this is the centre
                {{ questions.author }}
            </div>
            <div id = "rightBlock">
                <h2> Other questions</h2>
                {% for quest in questions %}
                    <h3><a href="">{{ quest.question }}</a></h3>
                    <p>{{ quest.text|linebreaks }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>

#contentBlock {
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 2px;
}
#centreBlock {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 39%;
    background-color: #fed325;
}
#leftBlock {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #25effe;
}
#rightBlock {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #25effe;
}
```

And this is what it looks like
[image: mismatched layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a `min-height` to all of your content blocks, based on the height of your largest content block to make sure they all stay the same size.

Also, if your elements have the display property set to `inline-block` you can use `vertical-align:middle` to make sure that all of your content blocks stay inline with each other.

There's a quick example here: [View CodePen](http://codepen.io/GKBeast/pen/aOExMp)

Answer (score 0):

You need use a min-height property.